# Enable mod_rewrite in Windows for .htaccess to work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat

I want to run my Angular 6 app over Apache Tomcat server. But every time I reload when in deep link URL then it shows status **404 page not found**. 
So, for that, I included the **.htaccess** file in the root folder where my index.html is.
But still, it doesn't work because maybe the **mod_rewrite** is not enabled.

To enable mod_rewrite I was searching for **httpd.conf** file where I have to make the changes. But in my '**C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0**' directory there is NO such file.

So how do i enable the mod_rewrite to make .htaccess work and reload my Angular app without an error?

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat doesn't use httpd.conf, that is an apache file. The location of the individual webapps are kept in their individual web.xml files, but the location of all the configs are in ../tomcat8/conf/server.xml and web.xml

Try WAMP or Apache2 instead of Tomcat

You need to direct the .htaccess file to load the `index.html` on each hit.

like

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|flv|mpeg|mpg|mp4)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ bootstrap.html [NC,L]
```

You will found this line in `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in `httpd.conf` file, the file will be under the `conf` folder. you need to remove the hash(#) from it and then restart the apache services.

If you want that setup in Tomcat, then what I did in sample project is added the below code in `webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0"
  metadata-complete="true">

  <display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
  <description>
     Welcome to Tomcat
  </description>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

   <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/test/index.html</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Here `/test/index.html` `test` is my project name, you can change it to yours but try to use the project web.xml to avoid other project redirection. and in that case you can directly add the `/index.html` in path

Comment: under conf folder there is no such file. I checked it many times. Infact there is no such file like httpd.conf in the directory i mentioned. So how do i enable the mod_rewrite?

Comment: Do you have this structure? `conf/virtual-hosts/default.conf` ?

Comment: Or find something like `conf/Catalina/my.domain.com/rewrite.config` here `my.domain.com` is example

Comment: Or you can use WAMP or Apache2 instead of Tomcat

Comment: I don't have this route - `conf/virtual-hosts/default.conf`, neither this- `conf/Catalina/my.domain.com/rewrite.config`.

Comment: If Tomcat is not the must, try WAMP or Apache2, the configuration will be easy

Comment: Tomcat is a must for my project. Is there any other alternative where on reloading of the app i don't get 404 error in Tomcat server?

Comment: try if this help https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/tomcat/apache-tomcat-rewrite-rules-example/

Comment: Yes i have tried that, but when i include this line `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />` then the tomcat itself doesn't work with 404 error index.cfm//index.jsp not found and same app reloading issue like before.

Comment: I have updated the answer, it tested it. Let me know if that works